# Visual Studio Code - TypeScript Definitions for MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to build a simple web application using `Node.js` and `Express`. After having installed both definitions using `tsd` as [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/runtimes/nodejs) guide shows.

Trying `tsd query mongodb --action install` it doesn't get error like `zero result` or something, but still can't show autocompletion on vscode.

I guess if it's posible to install even MongoDB definitions. Does it?

EDIT: `mongodb.d.ts` is in `typings\mongodb` folder in my project.

Comment: Have you put the file in the right folder and reference it correctly?

Comment: In which path it should be stored?

Comment: It should be located in the typings folder. And you should reference it correctly `/// <reference path="./typings/mongodb/mongodb.d.ts>`

Comment: Checked. There it is.

Comment: I miswrote module name. Don't know why MongoDB tutorial shows `require('mongoskin')` instead of `require('mongodb')`. luckily, trying to guess module name `mongodb`, it worked.

Comment: Apparently there's no `mongoskin` definition in tsd. You could check it yourself [here](http://definitelytyped.org/tsd/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My ignorance in MongoDB induced me to miswrote module name. [MongoDB tutorial](http://www.hacksparrow.com/mongoskin-tutorial-with-examples.html) shows `require('mongoskin')` instead of `require('mongodb')` I thought it could be the same thing but it isn't.

Luckily, replacing module name `mongoskin` with `mongodb`, it worked.